# Events Internals: In .net how are Events represented internally?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a basic doubt. Internally how are events represented as methods or as (fields)objects. If event is a field then how one can still contain events in the interface definition.

Thanks
JeeZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you type this:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

what the compiler generates is (simplified) this:

```
// declares a normal delegate of type 'EventHandler'
private EventHandler _myEvent;

// declares 'add_MyEvent' and 'remove_MyEvent' methods similar to a property
public event EventHandler MyEvent {
    add { _myEvent += value; }
    remove { _myEvent -= value; }
}
```

An event is similar to a property; a wrapper around a delegate that only allows methods to be added or removed. This is so you can't completely re-assign the delegate and delete other people's subscriptions to it.

All you are doing when specifying an event in an interface is that any implementing classes should have the `add` and `remove` methods for the event. Very similar to declaring a property on an interface, in fact.

This is also why you can only call or re-assign the event in the class it is declared in - any references to the `MyEvent` event within the class are re-routed to use the delegate directly, whereas outside the class you can only access the `add` and `remove` methods, not the delegate directly.

Comment: And the "simplified" is about as close as you can get without having to discuss at least 3 different compiler implementations ;-p

Answer (score 2):

@thecoop's answer is a very good description of "field-like events" (noting the "simplified" caveat) - but note that actually events can be implemented **any way you like**. All the event defines is an `add`/`remove` accessor pair (which is why it can be defined on the interface, like a property).

For example, with sparce events the following may be common:

```
private static readonly object FooKey = new object(), BarKey = new object();

public event EventHandler Foo {
    add {Events.AddHandler(FooKey, value);}
    remove {Events.RemoveHandler(FooKey, value);}
}
public event MouseClickEventHandler Bar {
    add {Events.AddHandler(BarKey, value);}
    remove {Events.RemoveHandler(BarKey, value);}
}
```

where `Events` is an `EventHandlerList`, usually delay-loaded:

```
private EventHandlerList events;
protected EventHandlerList Events {
    get {
        if(events == null) events = new EventHandlerList();
        return events;
    }
}
```

Or you could do anything else you like. Within reason (noting the expected behaviour of event subscriptions and delegate equality / composite delegates).

Comment: Another neat thing I do with event methods is implement a direct route-through to an event on a child control (for winforms) :)

Answer (score 0):

Events are not represented as fields nor methods. They are simply events, as far as the meta-data for a class is concerned.

Similarly properties have a special flag (although these get stored as methods with well known names).